# How to send android app to another user for beta testing?

Tags: android, cordova, beta-testing

I am developing a hybrid cordova app with Phonegap. How can I send this app to another user so that he can install it in his Android device and test my app?

thanks.

Comment: Your best bet would be the google Play beta release and test groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [alpha/beta testing & staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) in the Developer Console help. If you've got a small test base you can just build your app and send it out with the debug key. Make sure they've got the `Unknown Sources' option checked in Security settings.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use Google Developer console and setup beta and alpha testing with groups of users of your choice.

Here is a detailed [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

#### Main attractions:

You don’t need a production APK to publish an alpha/beta app.

If you're testing an existing app that you've published before, only users in your test group will receive an update for your Alpha/Beta version.

If you're testing a new app that you haven't published before, only users in your test group can find and download your app.

After publishing an alpha/beta APK, it may take up to 24 hours for your test link to be available to testers.

If you make any changes to your app's Pricing & Distribution page, including setting your app price to Paid or Free, it affects your production, alpha, beta, and any future versions of your app.